# Element not interactable (clickable) while scraping a website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with the code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rows, cols = (1000,11)
rows = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
driver_path = 'C:/Users/adith/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe'
brave_path = 'C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe'
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)

browser.get('https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops/ct-p/Laptops')

cookies = {
    'lithiumLogin:vjauj58549': '~2TtiW3OEsenvCn5Ir~fBcCal7YbmhAmxNWLe4LgaSRCss_g69Gqm2CAs-fDA_FtccFLDK3AoWuzXHz72fb'
}


def load():
    count = 0
    while True:
        page = requests.get(browser.current_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
        button = [z.text for z in soup.find_all(class_='lia-link-navigation')]
        print(button[-1])
        if(button[-1]=='Load more'):
            count = count + 1
            browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn-load-more"]').click()
            if(count>12):
                break
        else:
            break
            
try:
    load()
except:
    load()
```

It is able to click the load button 3 times but then I get an error as shown below.

```
Load more
Load more
Load more
Load more
Load more
Load more
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementClickInterceptedException          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ef6cae973b0d> in <module>
     18 try:
---> 19     load()
     20 except:

<ipython-input-6-ef6cae973b0d> in load()
     11             count = count + 1
---> 12             browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn-load-more"]').click()
     13             if(count>15):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in click(self)
     87         """Clicks the element."""
---> 88         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     89 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    395         params['id'] = self._id
--> 396         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    397 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    434         if response:
--> 435             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    436             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    246             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 247         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    248 

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (470, 1629)
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
```

Can someone please explain what's wrong with the code? Also, can anyone help me out to eliminate the use of BeautifulSoup library completely to get the required solution?

Comment: what do you want to get as a result?

Comment: There is no BeautifulSoup in your code. Tell us what are ytou trying to achieve after you load all the data in your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using requests and bs4 when you already have the browser via selenium, you should just use selenium without requests to do the same job:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import csv

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rows, cols = (1000,11)
rows = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]


driver_path = 'C:/Users/adith/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe'
brave_path = 'C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe'
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)

browser.get('https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops/ct-p/Laptops')

def load():
    count = 0
    while True:
        button = [z.text for z in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lia-link-navigation')]
        print(button[-1])

        if(button[-1]=='Load more'):
            count = count + 1
            browser.execute_script( "window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
            browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn-load-more"]').click()
            if(count>12):
                break
        else:
            break
            
try:
    load()
except:
    load()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are able to click the load button 3 times, that implies the [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver)

```
(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='btn-load-more']")
```

is ***perfecto***.

---

### Solution

Ideally to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='btn-load-more']"))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Initially, I got the same error when I ran the code but running the same code again gave me no errors at all. Weird but working perfectly now. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Try scrolling to the end of the page (where the button is located)  before clicking on it:

```
def load():
    count = 0
    while True:
        page = requests.get(browser.current_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
        button = [z.text for z in soup.find_all(class_='lia-link-navigation')]
        print(button[-1])
        if(button[-1]=='Load more'):
            count = count + 1
            browser.execute_script( "window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(1)
            browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btn-load-more"]').click()
            if(count>12):
                break
        else:
            break
```